# Recover innodb database from ibdata1 and *.frm files only

Tags: mysql, innodb, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a problem on my server.

I had a hard disk error on my server, and I restarted it. After that, I started wamp server software, but mysql services were not started.

I checked all mysql data, there were `mydb/mytable.frm`, `mydb/db.opt`, `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, `ibdata1` and other Configuration Settings files available; but `mydb/mytable.ibd` was not available.

Is it possible to recover my data? If yes, how?

Comment: If innodb_file_per_table is OFF, which is default setting, then you shouldn't have mytable.ibd.

To recover the database try to start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery=4 (try 5 and 6) and dump the database. If MySQL doesn't start with innodb_force_recovery=6 then fetch records from ibdata1 with https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb

Comment: @akuzminsky actually I don't have any idea on how to use https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb.

Can you have any article or video on which I can learn?

Comment: Any hints in the MySQL logs about what might be wrong?

Comment: @Ankur, see docs here http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool:mysql-data-recovery:start